# Firebase admin - Create Custom token: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier

Tags: firebase-admin

I'm using firebase admin becasue I want to validate my users in a different server. I have the following code but I'm getting the error

```
{ code: 'auth/user-not-found',
  message: 'There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.' } }
```

Docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

```
    var uid = user_dict['uid'];
    admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
        .then(function (customToken) {
            admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
                //email: user_dict['email'],
                emailVerified: true,
                displayName: user_dict['displayName'],
                photoURL: user_dict['photoURL']
            })
            .then(function(userRecord) {

                response = {
                    token:customToken
                };
                res.send(response);

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error updating user:", error);
                res.statusCode = 401;
                res.send("Error al actualizar usuario")
            });


        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
            res.statusCode = 401;
            res.send("El usuario no existe")
        });
```

The wierd part this code is working for 1 user, but not for the rest. Why?

## UPDATE

I change my code to this:

```
var uid = user_dict['uid'];
```

admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
    .then(function (customToken) {

```
    admin.auth().getUser(uid)
        .then(function(userRecord) {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
            console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
            admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
                email: user_dict['email'],
                emailVerified: true,
                displayName: user_dict['displayName'],
                photoURL: user_dict['photoURL']
            })
            .then(function(userRecord) {

                response = {
                    token:customToken
                };
                res.send(response);

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error updating user:", error);
                res.statusCode = 401;
                res.send("Error al actualizar usuario")
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);

            admin.auth().createUser({
                uid:uid,
                email: user_dict['email'],
                emailVerified: true,
                displayName: user_dict['displayName'],
                photoURL: user_dict['photoURL'],
                password:req.body['password']
            })
            .then(function(userRecord) {
                // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
                console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
                response = {
                    token:customToken
                };
                res.send(response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
                res.statusCode = 401;
                res.send("Error al crear el usuario")
            });

        });

})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.send("El usuario no existe")
});
```

You can see in the following screenshot carlos@mail is created using the function createUser() and the other email ricardo@mail is not. They don't have the same provider why such a difference?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createCustomToken()` accepts arbitrary user ID strings. But `updateUser()` does not. The UID passed to `updateUser()` must already exist in the Firebase project. You need to call `createUser()` to first create those user accounts in Firebase.

Comment: It's wierd. I swear that I have one user which i did not create and is updating well. I will update my question with an screenshot and you will see the user ricardo@mail and carlos@mail, ricardo@mail was never created using the funcion createUser() but as you can you he is in the user list.

Comment: If these users have ever logged in to the project via any app or API, that created the user accounts in the system.