# Firestore rules to match uid to subId

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, next-auth

I'm working on a project with NExtjs13, Firebase and Next auth with google provider..But with Next Auth, we only have initially access to 3 data(email, name and image) when user signIn.

```
user: {
name: 'projectX',
email: 'projectx@gmail.com',
image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com"}
```

So i manage to add more information with this callback function

```
export const authOptions = {

providers: [
GoogleProvider({
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID!,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET!,
 
 }),
],
callbacks: {
async jwt({ token, account, profile, user }: any) {
  
  if (account) {
    token.accessToken = account.access_token;
    token.uid = user?.id

  }
  return token;
},
async session({ session, token, user }: any) {
  session.user.token = token;
  return session;
},
},

};
```

(Which add a token to the user: the uid and sub are the same by the way)

```
 user: {
name: 'projectX anllia',
email: 'projectxanllia@gmail.com',
image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNmyxY9iVPQSKRgwH6R0v_pZFAU1AjGIRTM3cd0Fr4_=s96-c',
token: {
  name: 'projectX',
  email: 'projectx@gmail.com',
  picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/,
  sub: 'some random numbers' Ex: 756376576345763473,
  accessToken: 'very long string here',
  uid: 'some random numbers' Ex: 756376576345763473,,
  iat: 1682746047,
  exp: 1685338047,
  jti: 'a2edec2e-e61c-4f6a-9d6b-151ae2abd534'
}
```

}
}

Then in my load Checkout function, i have this (I basically retrieve the sub data and pass it to a const called usersSub and then pass it to the path) :

```
 const loadCheckout = async (priceId: string) => {
// @ts-ignore
const usersSub = session?.user?.token?.sub;
console.log(usersSub, "userSub  ID");
const payRef = await addDoc(
  collection(db, `customers/${usersSub}/checkout_sessions`),
  {
    price: priceId,
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  }
);
onSnapshot(payRef, async (snap) => {
  console.log(snap.data()?.url);

  if (snap.data()?.error) {
    // Show an error to your customer and
    // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
    alert(`An error occured: ${snap.data()?.error.message}`);
  }
  if (snap.data()?.url) {
    // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
    window.location.replace(snap.data()?.url);
  }
});
```

};

Now this is how i set my FireStore Security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow write, read: if true
     allow write: if request.auth !=null && 
request.auth.token.sub == ""
}

match /customers/{usersSub} {
  allow read: if request.auth.token.sub == usersSub;

  match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.token.sub == usersSub;
  }
  match /subscriptions/{id} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.sub == usersSub;
  }
  match /payments/{id} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.sub == usersSub;
  }
}

match /products/{id} {
  allow read: if true;

  match /prices/{id} {
    allow read: if true;
  }

  match /tax_rates/{id} {
    allow read: if true;
  }
}
}
}
```

But when i tried to checkout, it give me this error: "An error occured: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier."

So i think fireStore rules doesn’t get the usersSub data. How to match the uid to the sub ?? Someone suggested me here to add a wildcard usersSub but stil not working..

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685934/firebase-admin-create-custom-token-there-is-no-user-record-corresponding-to-t) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086080/firebase-cloud-function-return-error-error-there-is-no-user-record-correspondin)